# Concatenar valores de uma mesma coluna

Tags: sql-server, query, concatenação-de-string

Como faço pra concatenar os valores de uma mesma tabela

Exemplo de tabela

```
   | Usuario  |  Formulario  |    Acao    |  Permitir |
   |  Admin   |   Contrato   |  Imprimir  |     1     |
   |  Admin   |   Contrato   |  Consultar |     1     |
   |  Admin   |   Contrato   |   Editar   |     0     |
   |  Admin   |   Contrato   |   Excluir  |     1     |
```

Retorno

```
  | Formulario | Acao                         |
  |  Contrato  | Imprimir; Consultar; Excluir |
```

No retorno, preciso selecionar sempre o Formulario, e a Acao concatenar somente quando Permitir for igual a 1.

Meu código

```
SELECT 
  FormID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' +CAST(AcaoID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM PermissaoAcoesForms 
    WHERE (FormID = Results.FormID) AND FormID = 'CarteiraCompras' AND Permitir = 1 AND GrupoUsuario = 'Admin'
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS AcaoID
FROM PermissaoAcoesForms Results
GROUP BY FormID
```

Mas meu retorno está trazendo errado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer isso, veja se resolve seu problema.

```
SELECT s.formulario,
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN s.a1 = NULL THEN "" ELSE CONCAT(s.a1, " ;") END, 
              CASE WHEN s.a2 = NULL THEN "" ELSE CONCAT(s.a2, " ;") END, 
              CASE WHEN s.a3 = NULL THEN "" ELSE CONCAT(s.a3, " ;") END, 
              CASE WHEN s.a4 = NULL THEN "" ELSE CONCAT(s.a4, " ;") END) AS acao
  FROM (SELECT r.formulario,
               MAX(a1) AS a1,
               MAX(a2) AS a2,
               MAX(a3) AS a3,
               MAX(a4) AS a4
          FROM (SELECT formulario,
                       CASE WHEN acao = "Imprimir" AND permitir = 1 THEN "Imprimir" ELSE NULL END a1
                       CASE WHEN acao = "Consultar" AND permitir = 1 THEN "Consultar" ELSE NULL END a2
                       CASE WHEN acao = "Editar" AND permitir = 1 THEN "Editar" ELSE NULL END a3
                       CASE WHEN acao = "Excluir" AND permitir = 1 THEN "Excluir" ELSE NULL END a4
                  FROM tabela) r
         GROUP BY (r.formulario)) s
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar!

Comment: @IgorLessa, funcionou? Era o que queria?

Comment: Sim! Muito obrigado, fiz algumas modificações e utilizei Stuff, muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Comment: Que bom que a resposta foi útil amigo!

Answer (score 0):

**Achei um exemplo bacana desse site** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/6177bd7a-e2fc-46f4-9646-8fd1480cf14b/concatenar-valores-de-linhas-em-uma-coluna?forum=520

**Exemplo :**
**Codigo    Cliente Produto**

```
1   Jorge   piso
1   Jorge   porta
1   Jorge   torneira
```

**Preciso que o resultado deste select fique assim:**

```
Codigo  Cliente Produto
1   Jorge   piso;porta;torneira
```

-- **Concatenando**

```
SELECT  CODIGO,
        CLIENTE,
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT CAST(PRODUTO AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' AS [text()]
         FROM TABELA AS O
         WHERE O.CODIGO  = C.CODIGO
         and   O.CLIENTE = C.CLIENTE
         ORDER BY CODIGO
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS Produtos
FROM TABELA AS C
GROUP BY CODIGO,CLIENTE;
```